# ansible uri module fails (lineno\\": 0\\n}' is not of type u'object) (Input payload validation failed)

Tags: ansible

ansible 2.7, same call over curl works fine>

```
curl -X POST " -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"hostname\": \"string\", \"name\": \"string\", \"service\": \"string\", \"extra\": {}, \"args\": [ \"string\" ], \"module\": \"string\", \"filename\": \"string\", \"pathname\": \"string\", \"requestid\": \"string\", \"message\": \"string\", \"funcname\": \"string\", \"levelname\": \"INFO\", \"lineno\": 0}"
```

uri module gives me the following error:

[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note 2 that the implicit localhost does not match 'all' 3 4 5 PLAY [update log via api] ****************************************************** 20:37:30 6 7 TASK [uri] ********************************************************************* 20:37:30 8 [DEPRECATION WARNING]: Supplying headers via HEADER_* is deprecated. Please use 9 headers to supply headers for the request. This feature will be removed in 10 version 2.9. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting 11 deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg. 12 fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"access_control_allow_origin": "*", "changed": false, "connection": "Upgrade, close", "content": "{\"message\": \"Input payload validation failed\", \"errors\": {\"\": \"u'{\n \"hostname\": \"string\",\n \"name\": \"string\",\n \"service\": \"string\",\n \"extra\": {},\n \"args\": [\n \"string\"\n ],\n \"module\": \"string\",\n \"filename\": \"string\",\n \"pathname\": \"string\",\n \"requestid\": \"string\",\n \"message\": \"string\",\n \"funcname\": \"string\",\n \"levelname\": \"INFO\",\n \"lineno\": 0\n}' is not of type u'object'\"}}\n", "content_length": "469", "content_type": "application/json", "date": "Thu, 30 May 2019 01:37:35 GMT", "json": {"errors": {"": "u'{\n \"hostname\": \"string\",\n \"name\": \"string\",\n \"service\": \"string\",\n \"extra\": {},\n \"args\": [\n \"string\"\n ],\… 13 14 PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************* 20:37:37 15 localhost : ok=0 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  name: update log via api
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
   vars.yml
  vars:
  tasks:
  - uri:
      url: "{{ api_log_url }}"
      method: POST
      force_basic_auth: yes
      url_username: "{{ api_log_user }}"
      url_password: "{{ api_log_password }}"
      body_format: json
      return_content: yes
      HEADER_Content-Type: "application/json"
      validate_certs: false
      body: "{{ lookup('file','create_body.json') | to_json }}"
```

create_body.json:

```
{
  "hostname": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "service": "string",
  "extra": {},
  "args": [
    "string"
  ],
  "module": "string",
  "filename": "string",
  "pathname": "string",
  "requestid": "string",
  "message": "string",
  "funcname": "string",
  "levelname": "INFO",
  "lineno": 0
}
```

Comment: foremost: why don't you heed its advice and stop using deprecated syntax for the headers? secondarily, as a "stop making my eyes bleed," you should use single-quotes for your `curl` body since the entire payload is literal: `-d '{"hostname": "string", etc etc}'`

Comment: Also, had you not truncated your error message, we might be able to help you further, but here we are

Answer (score 0):

> `"json": {"errors": {"": "u'{\n \"hostname\": \"string\",\n`

I'm pretty sure you are getting bitten by the json-to-object-to-string mental bug; since you already have JSON text, the ideal outcome would not be to parse it into an object and then have ansible serialize it back into a string, lest you run the very real risk of exactly what happened here: calling `str(body)` where `body` was a `dict`

Just remove the `| to_json` from your `body: {{ }}` expression and I would expect it will end better than what you are currently experiencing